# JSP calls Servlet (not working)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request

I'am trying this code on the JSP page:

```
        <%
if((ArrayList<Car>) session.getAttribute("car_1") == null){
%>
  <jsp:forward page="/MyServlet.java"/>
<%}%>
```

When I run my project, I get error 404 with message:"The requested resource is not available."

I guess the problem is with the web.xml (I don't have one).Could be?

Comment: Are you really intending to link to the *source* code of your servlet?

Answer (score 1):

You are simply linking to the source code of a `MyServlet.java`file contained in your context. If there is none, you will get a 404 error.

You most probably added the `.java` by mistake. Try:

```
<jsp:forward page="/MyServlet"/>
```

I'm assumming your servlet (`WEB-INF/classes/your/package/MyServlet.class`) is correctly mapped via annotations:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/MyServlet"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet { ... }
```

or `web.xml`:

```
<web-app ...>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServletName</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>your.package.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServletName</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get this: 

The server side component of the HTTP Monitor has detected a java.lang.StackOverflowError.
This happens when there is an infinite loop in the web module.
Correct the cause of the infinite loop before running the web module again.

Comment: It seems that the error message answers that question, doesn't it? Check for an infinite loop in your servlet code.

Comment: @niarb seems like you're forwarding to your servlet and in your servlet you're forwarding to your JSP that will forward again to your servlet that will forward again to your JSP... you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you'll need web.xml with at least 2 tags:

```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.bla.blah.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

In JSP you'll need to use:

```
<jsp:forward page="/myservlet"/>
```

or

```
<jsp:forward page="/mywarfilename/myservlet"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried that...But netbeans/tomcat gave me this error:

FAIL - Deployed application at context path /MyProject but context failed to start
C:\Users\tcm\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1050: The module has not been deployed.

Comment: It's hard to say. Looks like you have issues with the servlet itself. Check all the Tomcat log files under Tomcat's log dir, especially catalina.out, probably you'll find more info there.

Comment: It should not be `/mywarfilename/myservlet` but `${request.contextPath/myservlet}`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of things

- it seems to me you forgot your web context
- you shouldn't forward to MyServlet.java but you should use the mapping you specified in the web.xml

Angelo

Comment: You don't really need `web.xml` *if* you are mapping it via annotations.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you append [`HttpServletRequest#contextPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29) to your pathin form of Expression Language:

```html
<jsp:forward page="${request.contextPath}/MyServlet"/>
```

Also, it would be better not using scriptlets at all, you can achieve the same behavior using JSTL:

```html
<c:if test="${empty car_1}">
    <jsp:forward page="${request.contextPath}/MyServlet"/>
</c:if>
```